# Angular2 plnkr error

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am working on  OS `ubuntu 14.04 LTS` and Google Chrome Browser `Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)` to run Angular2 projects.
But in most cases while searching something for angular2 i found number of plnkr is not working on this specified Operating system.
everytime i got some kind of errors like

> Uncaught TypeError: m.values is not a function
>
> Uncaught TypeError: e.values is not a function

why these error occured. while all those plnkr's are working fine on windows or any other platform. is this any bug with angular2 or something else ?
just want to use ng2-bootstrap for angular2 project but same error occured again for this website

> http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/

this link works on windows but not on ubuntu why ? for just reference i am posting this image.

[image]

Comment: Could you give us the complete stacktrace of the error? Thanks ;-)

Comment: what do you mean by `complete stacktrace` ? the whole error is shoing in the image :p

Answer (score 3):

This is because angular2 uses [Map](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.ts#L59), which is part of the [es6 draft](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-map-objects). Since this is not yet implemented in every browser you'll need to polyfill it and that's what [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) is for (see [compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Map)). I'm a little bit surprised that that chrome version doesn't still support it, but to be honest I don't know in what version they did add support for Maps. By using Chrome you should be good by just updating it to the latest version (*48.0.2564.109 m* at the moment I write this answer).

If you're using older browsers (even not that old), like IE, safari, Android browsers, etc, that doesn't support Maps you'll have to polyfill it.

See the [quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) under **Add the index.html** and see the polyfills required to make it work in other browsers.

**Reference**

- [angular2.dev.js:4045 Uncaught TypeError: m.values is not a function](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4997).

Comment: but i was thinking i am using one of the latest version of chrome. i don't know should i accept this answer or wait for more well explained answer. but be honest still m not clear how to remove this error. btw +1 for good answer, thanks

Comment: If you want to remove this error from the plnkrs, you should add the shim. In the case of the website you'll have to wait until someone fixes it (already asked for it [here](https://gitter.im/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap?at=56c1e2f34dfe1fa71ffce3d4)). If this doesn't solve your issue, you should provide the plnkr that's causing the issue for you.