# Angular2 - view not updated after http call

Tags: angular

Here is my setup (super simplified):

template:

```
<button (click)="doNothing">Show</button>
<h2>{{count}}</h2>
```

component:

```
count: number;
constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
    this.init();      
}

private init(): void {
    this._dataService.getAll().subscribe(res=> { //just a simple http GET here
        this.count = res;
        console.log(this.count); //logs the correct value, but view not updated
    });
}        

private doNothing(): void { }
```

As you may have noticed, I'm using a `button` that's not doing anything, but unless I click it my view is not updated with the correct value (took me some time to think of this hack). What am I actually doing here and how can I replace it with something not so dumb? All the http samples I found assured me that this should work without any magic, but apparently it doesn't. I'm using beta6

Comment: Try moving `this.init()` call from constructor to `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @Sasxa I tried this, didn't help

Comment: Seems like it should be working: http://plnkr.co/edit/yFGC8fC1HOw6D9xp4hOS?p=preview .

Comment: I have a few http calls populating lists here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/http Not sure this is what you are looking for, but you can see the code here:https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples/blob/master/components/http/http.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should indeed work as expected, no magic required, the problem was in my web browser (I was using Chrome Version 48.0.2564.109 m). I switched to Edge 20.10240.16384.0 and everything is fine now

Answer (score 3):

Simple workaround for this problem can be to use [NgZone](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html).
NgZone is an injectable service for executing work inside or outside of the Angular zone. So, it can be used to trigger the change detection manually.

```
import {NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
count: number;
private zone: NgZone;
constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
    this.zone = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: false });
    this.init();      
}

private init(): void {
    this._dataService.getAll().subscribe(res=> { //just a simple http GET here
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.count = res;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't solve my problem, I found a solution however

Comment: This is a more appropriate solution to the described problem.

Comment: Thank you!! This has just solved days of angular-angst for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have included the angular2-polyfills.js file into your main HTML? This file contains ZoneJS that is responsible from triggering view updates.

Comment: yes, I did, looks like the problem was with my web browser, you can see my own answer with details

Comment: This makes me think about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409958/angular2-plnkr-error. Perhaps adding es6-shim would fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem and using the workaround provided by @SaUrAbH MaUrYa it worked. 
But I was not satified with this, so searching more I found another way, that seems better:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService.getAll().subscribe(res=> this.count = res);}
```

For me, It works. I hope it works for you either