# Visual Studio 2015, ASP.NET 5, MVC 6, Angular 2.0 - Exception: Token must be defined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, angular

I am trying to put together a project running ASP.NET 5 using MVC6 and angular 2.0

- My typescript version is 1.7.6
- VS2015 - Update 1
- Angular Version is beta 2

I have got it to the stage where most of the errors are

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.21",
    "zone.js": "0.5.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/appScripts/",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My app.ts:

```
"use strict"
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: 'My First Angular 2 App'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

and my boot.ts:

```
"use strict"
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app'
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

lastly my html file looks like this

```
<script src="~/lib/angular2/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2/system.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2/rx.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2/angular2.dev.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.config({
                packages: {
                    appScripts: {
                        format: 'register',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
        <script>

            System.import('appScripts/boot')
                  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
```

Finally the actual error stack

```
EXCEPTION: Token must be defined!
BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23094
ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1185
(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12734
Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13438
NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13400
ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ angular2.dev.js:12712
bootstrap @ angular2.dev.js:24805
**execute @ boot.ts:4**
u @ system.js:5
execute @ system.js:5
b @ system.js:4
x @ system.js:4
p @ system.js:4
h @ system.js:4
(anonymous function) @ system.js:4
Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451
(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123
Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
```

[image: angular.dev 9745 breakpoint result]

Any help would be appreciated. I believe it's happening whilst bootstrapping the application I notice the execute is happening on boot.ts rather than my generated boot.js file - I'm not sure if this is part of the problem or not.

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: angular2 version is beta 6

Comment: Did you identify where this error occurs? I mean when bootstrapping the application, at component level?

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint at line 9745 in file `http://localhost:19637/lib/angular2/angular2.dev.js` so you will be able to see which provider can't be resolved?

Comment: To do that go to the Sources tab of chrome developer tools, select the file and click in the margin at the level of this line. Then reload your page. The browser will then stop at this line...

Comment: will do - I've also edited a couple of details on the question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to set "target": "es5" in tsconfig.json and to create a new .ts file (I called it shim-es6.ts) with the interfaces required to allow the build to complete.

I found some of the information on the [typescript github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3290)

I then found lib.es6.d.ts from the typescript library and pulled out the remaining interfaces - I've copied my finished shim-es6.ts file below for others reference.

Many Thanks to Theirry who helped me to work through the issues.

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    clear(): void;
    delete(key: K): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, index: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    get(key: K): V;
    has(key: K): boolean;
    set(key: K, value: V): Map<K, V>;
    size: number;
}
interface MapConstructor {
    new (): Map<any, any>;
    new <K, V>(): Map<K, V>;
    new <K, V>(iterable: Iterable<[K, V]>): Map<K, V>;
    prototype: Map<any, any>;
}
declare var Map: MapConstructor;
interface Set<T> {
    add(value: T): Set<T>;
    clear(): void;
    delete(value: T): boolean;
    entries(): IterableIterator<[T, T]>;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, index: T, set: Set<T>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    has(value: T): boolean;
    keys(): IterableIterator<T>;
    size: number;
    values(): IterableIterator<T>;
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
    [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
}

interface SetConstructor {
    new (): Set<any>;
    new <T>(): Set<T>;
    new <T>(iterable: Iterable<T>): Set<T>;
    prototype: Set<any>;
}
declare var Set: SetConstructor;

/**
 * Represents the completion of an asynchronous operation
 */
interface Promise<T> {
    /**
    * Attaches callbacks for the resolution and/or rejection of the Promise.
    * @param onfulfilled The callback to execute when the Promise is resolved.
    * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
    * @returns A Promise for the completion of which ever callback is executed.
    */
    then<TResult>(onfulfilled?: (value: T) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>): Promise<TResult>;
    then<TResult>(onfulfilled?: (value: T) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => void): Promise<TResult>;

    /**
     * Attaches a callback for only the rejection of the Promise.
     * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
     * @returns A Promise for the completion of the callback.
     */
    catch(onrejected?: (reason: any) => T | PromiseLike<T>): Promise<T>;
    catch(onrejected?: (reason: any) => void): Promise<T>;

    [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
}

interface PromiseConstructor {
    /** 
      * A reference to the prototype. 
      */
    prototype: Promise<any>;

    /**
     * Creates a new Promise.
     * @param executor A callback used to initialize the promise. This callback is passed two arguments: 
     * a resolve callback used resolve the promise with a value or the result of another promise, 
     * and a reject callback used to reject the promise with a provided reason or error.
     */
    new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;

    /**
     * Creates a Promise that is resolved with an array of results when all of the provided Promises 
     * resolve, or rejected when any Promise is rejected.
     * @param values An array of Promises.
     * @returns A new Promise.
     */
    all<T>(values: Iterable<T | PromiseLike<T>>): Promise<T[]>;

    /**
     * Creates a Promise that is resolved or rejected when any of the provided Promises are resolved 
     * or rejected.
     * @param values An array of Promises.
     * @returns A new Promise.
     */
    race<T>(values: Iterable<T | PromiseLike<T>>): Promise<T>;

    /**
     * Creates a new rejected promise for the provided reason.
     * @param reason The reason the promise was rejected.
     * @returns A new rejected Promise.
     */
    reject(reason: any): Promise<void>;

    /**
     * Creates a new rejected promise for the provided reason.
     * @param reason The reason the promise was rejected.
     * @returns A new rejected Promise.
     */
    reject<T>(reason: any): Promise<T>;

    /**
      * Creates a new resolved promise for the provided value.
      * @param value A promise.
      * @returns A promise whose internal state matches the provided promise.
      */
    resolve<T>(value: T | PromiseLike<T>): Promise<T>;

    /**
     * Creates a new resolved promise .
     * @returns A resolved promise.
     */
    resolve(): Promise<void>;

    [Symbol.species]: Function;
}

declare var Promise: PromiseConstructor;
interface IteratorResult<T> {
    done: boolean;
    value?: T;
}
interface Iterator<T> {
    next(value?: any): IteratorResult<T>;
    return?(value?: any): IteratorResult<T>;
    throw?(e?: any): IteratorResult<T>;
}

interface Iterable<T> {
    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T>;
}
interface IterableIterator<T> extends Iterator<T> {
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
}

interface Symbol {
    /** Returns a string representation of an object. */
    toString(): string;

    /** Returns the primitive value of the specified object. */
    valueOf(): Object;

    [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
}

interface SymbolConstructor {
    /** 
      * A reference to the prototype. 
      */
    prototype: Symbol;

    /**
      * Returns a new unique Symbol value.
      * @param  description Description of the new Symbol object.
      */
    (description?: string | number): symbol;

    /**
      * Returns a Symbol object from the global symbol registry matching the given key if found. 
      * Otherwise, returns a new symbol with this key.
      * @param key key to search for.
      */
    for(key: string): symbol;

    /**
      * Returns a key from the global symbol registry matching the given Symbol if found. 
      * Otherwise, returns a undefined.
      * @param sym Symbol to find the key for.
      */
    keyFor(sym: symbol): string;

    // Well-known Symbols

    /** 
      * A method that determines if a constructor object recognizes an object as one of the 
      * constructor’s instances. Called by the semantics of the instanceof operator. 
      */
    hasInstance: symbol;

    /** 
      * A Boolean value that if true indicates that an object should flatten to its array elements
      * by Array.prototype.concat.
      */
    isConcatSpreadable: symbol;

    /** 
      * A method that returns the default iterator for an object. Called by the semantics of the 
      * for-of statement.
      */
    iterator: symbol;

    /**
      * A regular expression method that matches the regular expression against a string. Called 
      * by the String.prototype.match method. 
      */
    match: symbol;

    /** 
      * A regular expression method that replaces matched substrings of a string. Called by the 
      * String.prototype.replace method.
      */
    replace: symbol;

    /**
      * A regular expression method that returns the index within a string that matches the 
      * regular expression. Called by the String.prototype.search method.
      */
    search: symbol;

    /** 
      * A function valued property that is the constructor function that is used to create 
      * derived objects.
      */
    species: symbol;

    /**
      * A regular expression method that splits a string at the indices that match the regular 
      * expression. Called by the String.prototype.split method.
      */
    split: symbol;

    /** 
      * A method that converts an object to a corresponding primitive value.
      * Called by the ToPrimitive abstract operation.
      */
    toPrimitive: symbol;

    /** 
      * A String value that is used in the creation of the default string description of an object.
      * Called by the built-in method Object.prototype.toString.
      */
    toStringTag: symbol;

    /**
      * An Object whose own property names are property names that are excluded from the 'with'
      * environment bindings of the associated objects.
      */
    unscopables: symbol;
}
declare var Symbol: SymbolConstructor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined an outDir property, I think that you should add a map entre in your SystemJS configuration.

You could try something like that:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      appScripts: 'wwwroot/ appScripts'
    },
    packages: {
      appScripts: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Make sure that the `wwwroot` folder is accessible through your web server.

Comment: Thanks,I've tried this but unfortunately doesn't help, the outDir is specified because the typescript directory sits outside of the web server - wwwroot is the root directory of the website, and the typescript generates the javascript files to the appScripts folder in the webserver (Scripts where the typescript files sit is not accessible via the webserver)

Comment: Okay, I see! Are your compiled JS files located directly into a sub folder called `appScripts`?

Comment: Could you try to set `"target": "es5"` instead of `"target": "es6"` in your TypeScript compiler configuration?

Comment: I think the es5 / es6 is probably a large part of the issue here, but when I change it to es5 I get a bunch of build errors relating to "Cannot find name 'Map'"

Comment: Perhaps this question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409958/angular2-plnkr-error?noredirect=1?